# UDP unicast: two processes listening on same udp port; only one receiving packets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

Purpose:
to receive UDP unicast packets sent to a single port in two different processes.

System: Linux, Language: C

I am able to bind two sockets in two different processes to the same port using SO_REUSEADDR. But, as expected, the packets are received in only one(the one bound later).

Is it possible to receive packets in both the processes? If not, how is tcpdump able to read but not consume packets.

Comment: What do you want? To inspect datagrams? → use an AF_PACKET socket or libpcap. To do some processing and send responses? → use multicast. To do some load balancing? → use some load-balancing proxy/router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why unicast? This is exactly what multicast is for.

To answer you second question - `tcpdump` gets a *copy* of each packet it listens to via something called [`bpf`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Packet_Filter), and that has to be explicitly supported by the network card driver.

Comment: `tcpdump` gets packets via a "tap" placed by opening an AF_PACKET (or equivalent) socket, which plugs just above the network card drivers (IIRC in `netif_rx` on Linux). You can place a BPF filter on top of that socket to filter the frames/datagrams you are interesting in.

Comment: Yes, I Linux is different from traditional BSD world. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: re "copy of each packet it listens to via something called bpf" should read "copy of each packet it listens to via something called [a layer 2 AF_PACKET socket]"

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with sockets API, and tcpdump picks packets right from network interface, before any TCP/IP processing.

Your only chance is to receive packets in one process and resend them to another one.

Comment: This is mostly true, though there have been some OSs in the past (Solaris seems to come to mind, though I could be wrong) that allowed multiple processes to open and read the same TCP port (and, I presume, UDP port) and read.  It was a cheap, semi-transparent form of load balancing that didn't always work well in practice.

To the OP: you should reconsider your app's design if you think you need this.  While I recognize that there are probably legit uses for what you describe, it's far more probable that you're going down the wrong path.

Comment: This was actually possible, but each TCP connection was only read by single process, one which accept()ed it first. OP wants to to read same data from two socket, twice. Alas, can't do.

Answer (score 1):

If you open a socket, bind, listen, then fork() your process, incoming connection requests will be handed, each time, to a randomly selected, single one of those processes (I've never bothered to figure out the strategy that Linux uses because it balances the load well).

I am currently testing that same behavior with a UDP server.